# Using Theme Lib Css / Source In Modules

Tags: magento2, module, less-css, less-import

If using the _module.less convention in a custom module - do we have access to all of the files included there (lib-clearfix, etc)?

Is this the only way or are there other methods that have been found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Vendor/Module/view//css/source/_module.less the css will all be compiled into the main Magento styelsheets and you will also have access to the mixins and variables define there, although load order is another question.